# create-react-app my-app --typescript vs. --template typscript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

What is the difference between

```
npx create-react-app my-app --typescript
```

and

```
npx create-react-app my-apptts --template typescript
```

?

The latter one is mentioned on the [official documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/), but `npm start` for it leads to errors (that shall not be discussed here - at this question I just want to understand the differences between both commands)

Comment: I think --template typescript is the "new" way to create a typescript project. Before the v17 of react I was able to create a typescript project with --typescript flag but now It generates me js file instead of ts file. So now you jut have to use --template typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typescript` flag has been deprecated since Create React App **v4.0.0**

> We've removed the deprecated typescript flag when creating a new app. Use `--template typescript` instead. We've also dropped deprecated NODE_PATH flag as this has been replaced by setting the base path in jsconfig.json.

[Official Changelog](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#removed-typescript-flag-and-node_path-support)

Comment: thanks for the official source. Using `--typescript` confusingly doesn't give an error.

Comment: Thank you. Yes indeed, they should've added some warnings to let us know that.